# React JS not rerendering html5 audio tag correctly

Tags: javascript, html, audio, reactjs

I am using React JS with the Spotify Web API to implement an web api search, and each page shows 10 results, and a next button. Each track has an html5 audio tag, which allows me to play a preview of the song. When the next 10 results are rendered, the html renders correctly (with the new audio source) but when I play it, it plays the songs from the original 10 results.

Interestingly, the second page displays the first set of songs, and then from the third page you can hear the second set of songs. Everything else (album art, title) updates correctly.

How can I fix this issue?

[image: track and html]

page render code:

```
pageGet(page) {
   var value = false;
   Object.keys(this.state.inputs).map(key => {
     if (this.state.inputs[key] != "") {
       value = true;
     }
   });
   if (value) {
     var url = this.buildUrl(page);
     axios.get(url)
     .then((res) => {
       this.setState({
         items: res.data.tracks.items,
         total: res.data.tracks.total,
         page: page
       })
     });
   }
 }
```

renders:

```
   <SpotifyResults
     tracks={this.state.items}
     page={this.state.page}
     total={this.state.total}
     next={this.next.bind(this)}
   />
```

Spotify Results:

```
displayTracks() {
  return this.props.tracks.map((track, i) => {
    return (
      <SpotifyTrack
        key={i}
        track={track}
      />
    );
  });
}
```

Spotify Track:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="track-container">
      <div className="album-cover">
        <img src={this.props.track.album.images[0].url}/>
      </div>
        <div className="track-header">
          <p>{this.displayTitle()}</p>
          <br/>
          <span>{this.props.track.artists[0].name}</span>
        </div>
      <div className="track-player">
          <audio controls>
            <source src={this.props.track.preview_url+".mp3"} type="audio/mpeg"/>
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
          </audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Update: I fixed this issue by providing unique keys when rendering the spotify tracks, including the page number. I made the key: i + (this.props.page-1)*10), instead of just the index of the current set of tracks.